# Which music player is suitable for me?

Tags: kubuntu, software-recommendation, music

I'm currently using kubuntu, having been a pure win 10 user before that.
I'm used to listening to music offline. I used to use a software called foobox (an fork of foobar2000) to manage a huge library of locally stored music.

But since I started using linux, I haven't found a suitable alternative. I need a music player that can play lossless formats (such as dsf, flac or wav), that can support creating and managing playlists, and that supports .cue file recognition.

I didn't like the so-called best music player for linux systems recommended by many articles. I have archived at least 1500 tracks and have created multiple folders according to different archive times and music genres.

Many of the popular players are disrupting my work by piling all the music together at once, especially when I'm ready to fix newly acquired music (think of the effort it takes to simply find the music that needs to be processed among thousands of tracks).

Comment: Can have a look at this link for alternative software.  Will list some, but you will need to test.  https://alternativeto.net/software/foobar2000/?platform=linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all music player softwares:

Rhythmobox

Audacious

Clementine

Amarok

DeaDBeeF

CMUS

Spotify

Sayonara

MOC

Exaile

Museeks

Lollypop

Strawberry

VLC

Harmony

Mellow

The links I used are:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/best-music-player-apps-ubuntu-linux https://www.tecmint.com/best-music-players-for-ubuntu-linux-mint/ http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/best-linux-music-players-to-stream-online-music

Note

1. That there may be some music player that can't be installed because of your ubuntu version is not compatible with the music software.
2. The links I used may not work in the future.
3. Rhythmobox should be default installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have found Audacious is wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use VLC media player, which can be installed through snap and apt. It also has support for add-ons, so you might be able to find an add-on for any features that the default VLC is missing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have found a very suitable software. It's Audacious, it works very good!